# PHP variable in soap array

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I'm trying to consume a soap webservice with PHP.
At this moment it's working fine while I "hardcode" the parameters.
But now I need to use variables instead of using static values.

I've got this array:

```
$params = Array('transactionId' => '123');
```

This will return me this transaction id status.

But now whe I use this:

```
$params = Array('transactionId' => $id);
```

I get

> 'There is a parameter not valid'

Is there any way to use a PHP variable in this array?

Kind regards

Comment: If `$params` is different in those two cases, it's because `$id !== '123'`. How are you setting the variable?

Comment: The variable comes from a form by POST from an other .php file. So what I need is to load the transaction ID in that form and then invoke the soap web service with the transaction ID I've send from the form.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($id);` directly before `$params`?

Comment: Now I see that there are several spaces after the value in the variable. Is there any way to take away that spaces?

Comment: I've used this var_dump(trim($id)); but can't put it into the array parameter

Comment: Solved! thak you very much!